# Up arrow at an empty prompt in ksh93

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh, command-history, line-editor

This is a request for explanation or pointer to documentation.

I'm a KornShell93 (`ksh` on Mac OS X or `ksh93` elsewhere) user. I like the shell for its relative simplicity as an interactive shell and for its scripting capabilities, and I've been using it since the code was made more free in 2000. I use it in `vi` editing mode, with both the `vi` and `viraw` options set.

There's a neat feature in `ksh93` that allows you to start typing a command on the command line and then press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> to get the latest matching command line  out of the command line history. I can find the documentation for this and how it's bound to `[count][A` in `vi` editing mode, no problem.

However, if I press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> at an empty prompt, it first gives me the most recently executed command, then it starts cycling through whatever command prefix I had previously looked for. This annoys me no ends.

Example:

I execute these three commands:

```
$ ls -l
$ ls -ld test
$ ls -ld testdir
```

Typing `ls` and then pressing <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> three times will cycle through them in opposite order.

Later, with many more commands issued, but no history searches and no `ls` invocations:

```
$ cc -o testrun mytest.c
$ man strncmp
```

If I now press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> once, I get `man strncmp`. If I press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> again, I get `ls -ld testdir` and then `ls -ld test` rather than the command `cc -o testrun mytest.c` and then the previous before that.

I'm looking for pointers for how to "fix" this so that <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> without typing anything on the command line beforehand cycles through the most recent history without trying search for a previously used prefix. Even a pointer to somewhere where the behaviour above is documented would be nice.

**EDIT**:

The `ksh93` manual says

> `[count]k`  Fetch previous command.  Each time `k` is entered the previous command back in time is accessed.
>
> `/string`   Search backward through history for a previous command  containing `string`.  `String` is terminated by a `RETURN` or `NEW LINE`.  If `string` is preceded by a `^`,  the  matched  line  must begin with `string`.  If `string` is null, the previous `string` will be used.
>
> `[count][A`   If cursor is at the end of the line it  is  equivalent  to  `/`  with `string` set to the contents of the current line.  Otherwise, it is equivalent to `k`.

This does *not* explain why I *first* get `man strncmp` (as if pressing <kbd>k</kbd>) and *then* get `ls -ld testdir` in my example above. With the text of the manual in mind, I would expect to get `ls -ld testdir` on the first press of <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> (which would be even more annoying, by the way).

Comment: sounds like a bug.  report it to whoever maintains the version of `ksh93` that you're using.

Comment: I can confirm this appears to be normal behaviour for ksh93 when in Vi Editing mode.  Up-Arrow performs a search, while `[ESC] [k] [k] ...` scrolls back through history until you hit the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it is documented behaviour.  From the ksh93 man page:

> Search Edit Commands
>     These commands access your command history.
>
> `[count]k`  Fetch  previous  command.   Each time k is entered the previous command back in time is accessed.
>
> `[count]-`  Equivalent to k.
>
> `[count][A` If cursor is at the end of the line it is equivalent to  `/` with *string* set to the contents of the current line. Otherwise, it is equivalent to `k`.
>
> `[count]j`  Fetch next command.  Each time `j` is entered  the  next command forward in time is accessed.
>
> `/`*string*   Search backward through history for a previous command containing *string*.  *String* is terminated by a `RETURN' or`NEW LINE'.
>   If *string* is  preceded  by  a  `^`,  the matched  line  must  begin  with *string*.  If *string* is null, the previous string will be used.

Note: When using Up-Arrow  after entering a string, the search string will be *anchored* to the start of the line, as if `^` was typed in front.

Example:

```
$ ls[Up-Arrow]
```

is the equivalent of

```
$ [ESC]/^ls
```

Comment: In all these years I've haven't seen that passage!! And I've read the manual several times a month. Big thanks!

Comment: Actually, now I wonder if I'm seeing the described behaviour. Why do I *first* get the previous line (as if `k`) and *then* a history search on the previous pattern?

Comment: There's no overlap with that previous line?   What version of ksh93 is this?
Try `print -v .sh.version` - results in `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01` on my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01` is the one shipped with Mac OS X too, and it's the same under RedHat and OpenBSD (same `ksh` version). The prompt is fresh, and then I press up-arrow. I'd expect that it would behave as `/string` with a null `string` since the cursor is at the end (and beginning) of the line, but instead it behaves as `k` *and then* as `/string` with null `string`.

Comment: Confirmed.  I see the same behaviour now.  Looks like a real bug.